# Sum of Bernoulli variables with known probabilities

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Following the ideas from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121829/sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables) and, especially, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/how-can-i-efficiently-model-the-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables), i was wondering if the a sum of two independent groups of Bernoulli distributed variables whose probabilities are know *a priori* is a Poisson-Binomial distribution (according to [Le Cam's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem)), and a few other questions. To add some context, have:

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ follow a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p = 1$. So: $$X_i \sim Bern(p_i = 1), \forall{i} \in 1,...,n$$

Also let $X_{n+1}, ..., X_N$ follow a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p = 0.5$. So:
$$X_j \sim Bern(p_j = 0.5), \forall{j} \in n+1,...,N$$

Then, does the following statement still apply?
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i \sim \text{Poisson-Binomial}$$

Given that the probabilities are known, the only "parameters" are **N** and **n**. Suppose that **N** is known as well, and **n** is not known. Is there any way to estimate **n**, for a given large enough **N** (N > 100). If it is possible, how sure can i be of the estimate?

Comment: You can substantially simplify your question with a tiny bit of analysis.  Your $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are *constantly* equal to $1,$ and so they introduce a *constant* additive term of $n$ in the sum.  The sum of the $X_{n+1},\ldots, X_N$ has a Binomial$(N-n,1/2)$ distribution.  Thus, $S_n$ has a *shifted Binomial* distribution. Because $N$ is not terribly small, Maximum Likelihood will perform well.  It is so strange to add a value of $n$ by prescribing a set of Bernoulli variables, though, I have to ask: is this how you intended your question to be interpreted?

Comment: Yes, @whuber. The main question was if $S_n$ followed a Poisson-Binomial (now i know it doesn't, thanks to you). To give some context, the problem i'm trying to model is basically two groups of people answering a question with two alternatives. $n$ know the answer ($p_i$ = 1) and $N-n$ dont know ($p_j$ = 0.5). The size of $n$ determines the "mean probability" of the two groups added. That is why  $n$, odd as it may seem, is important.